# Output all links from website

Tags: website, web

I've read related questions, but haven't get answer.
I need to download all images from a simple html site. It has a lot of pages. I'm going to grab all images links from all pages (then I'll download them with php on hosting).

Is it a tool that can analyze site and output all links from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, you can create a simple parser in PHP that scrapes the content of the site and then downloads it automatically. Since you say that you'll download the images using PHP, I presume that you have the skills to write a small spider.

However, I would refer you to stackoverflow with that question.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can write parser, but maybe there is a good tool that can make that work.

Comment: @Tuco, I don't know if there is a good tool for this, but I haven't come across such a tool. That is the reason I have written quite a few boring crawlers... BTW, you can mark my answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the empty checkmark next to my answer :) Cheers and good luck :)